# jQuerys append rows and columns

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a dynamic table with jQuery. So far I have this code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    while(i<10){
        $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
        $('tr').append('<td></td>');
        i++;
    };
});
```

It gives me a rather strange result : I get a table as expected, but the first row has 10 columns, the second row has 9 columns and so on...

I was surprised by the result, I was expecting 10 rows with one column.

Comment: On every iteration you're appending `td` to all available `tr`, as that's what `$('tr').append('<td></td>');` does

Answer (score 3):

First you need to select the table and hold it in a variable

```
var table = $('table');
```

in the while loop, you create a new `tr` element

```
var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
```

append it to the table

```
table.append(tr);
```

then you append a new `td` element

```
tr.append('<td></td>')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('tr').append('<td></td>');
```

This selects every `<tr>` in the entire document (including the ones you’ve added in previous iterations) and adds a `<td>` to each one. The smallest fix is probably to insert both at once:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;

    while (i < 10) {
        $('table').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
        i++;
    }
});
```

Comment: not an optimal solution.. 10 times $('table') is referenced.

Comment: @vinayakj: It’s a minimal fix, not an optimal solution. I had included a suggestion to store `$(table)`, use a `for` loop, and remove `$(document).ready`, but I decided it wasn’t important.

Comment: fix is understood.. but its better if we clear his basic understanding.. here its just `<tr>` but it can be whole component template. OP should know how to handle those situations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold the handle to append the elements to same element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
var rowTemplate = '<tr></tr>';
var $table = $('table');
    while(i<10){
        var $row = $(rowTemplate);
        $row.appendTo($table);
        $row.append('<td> cell '+i+'</td>');
        i++;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: Why do we have to define first var rowTemplate = '<tr></tr>'; and then during the iteration  var $row = $(rowTemplate);? couldn't we just define var $row = '<tr></tr>'?

Comment: if you define it in loop then `td` would get appened to same `tr` as everytime you are getting same handle.